# Missing Gem called "rails"?? Very confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a rake db:create

And get the following message:

Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.10, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I'm brand new to Rails and have no idea what I'm doing so any help is very appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to use rails (rake), yet you don't seem to have rails installed...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your console and run

```
bundle install
```

you may need to

```
sudo bundle install.
```

If you check the Gemfile of your application `<APPLICATION_ROOT>/Gemfile`, you should see something like

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
...
```

When you run `bundle install`, it grabs all the gems you have listed in your Gemfile to make sure you can run your application.

If you get an error trying to run `bundle install` or `sudo bundle install`, first run `gem install bundler` or `sudo gem install bundler`.

Whether or not you need the `sudo` will depend on how your ruby installation is set up.

**EDIT**: Problem appears to be related to ruby versioning issues (go figure!), I've suggested that he install [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) or an easier to read guide for [mac](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/)

Comment: your Gemfile is in your application root/Gemfile.  Go to the directory where you set up the application and you should see the Gemfile there.

If you setup your app by typing something like `rails mytestapp` you will find it in `mytestapp/Gemfile`

Comment: Am I running bundle install in /testApp? or in my root?

Comment: In the root of your application as it needs to see the `Gemfile`. Basically, the same folder your `Gemfile` is in.

ie. 

If you were to have installed your app in `~/projects/mytestapp` and your `Gemfile` is in `~/projects/mytestapp/Gemfile`; run `bundle install` from the `~/projects/mytestapp` directory.

Comment: I did that. Tried to do the same command as above and got the same error after doing bundle install...

Comment: Can you type `gem list` (possibly `sudo gem list`) and paste the output?

Comment: @ZackShapiro let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2976/discussion-between-kristian-pd-and-zack-shapiro)